# Which formula to choose for a mixed model / multilevel model

Tags: mixed-model, modeling, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I'm trying to write a mixed model on repeated data, but I am having a hard time writing the formula.

My database is composed of results of schools for different exams.
Each line contains a result from 0 to 100. For each result I know the school, the year it was taken, and the subject of the exam. I separated the schools in two kinds (A and B); my objective is to measure if the kind (A or B) of a school has an influence on its result. However, as I said, I have repeated measures for each school because I have 20 grades by school, one for each year (2014 to 2019) and one for each of four subjects.
Here is an example of my data:

```r
       Result School_ID Year    Subject School_type
1      19         1 2015       math           A
2      35         1 2015    english           A
3       4         1 2015    history           A
4      16         1 2015 philosophy           A
5      55         1 2016       math           A
6      62         1 2016    english           A
7      74         1 2016    history           A
8      66         1 2016 philosophy           A
9      32         1 2017       math           A
10     16         1 2017    english           A
11     42         1 2017    history           A
12     52         1 2017 philosophy           A
13     95         1 2018       math           A
14      8         1 2018    english           A
15     35         1 2018    history           A
16     41         1 2018 philosophy           A
17     12         1 2019       math           A
18     40         1 2019    english           A
19     56         1 2019    history           A
20     65         2 2019 philosophy           B
21     12         2 2015       math           B
22     23         2 2015    english           B
23     45         2 2015    history           B
24     90         2 2015 philosophy           B
25      3         2 2016       math           B
26     66         2 2016    english           B
27     51         2 2016    history           B
28     26         2 2016 philosophy           B
29      4         2 2017       math           B
```

Because I have repeated data, I know I have to use a mixed model using `lmer` (for instance).
However, I am struggling to find a good formula.

Firstly I tried this:

```r
Result ~ School_type * Subject + (1|Year)
```

But I'm not really sure that is a good formula.
I also tried this

```r
Result ~ School_type * Subject + (Year|School_ID)
```

But it does not give any significant result. At first I thought my variables `School_type` had no significant influence on Result. Which was reeally unexpected. Then I thought, that by considering the school as a random variable, this formula was suppressing the effect of the school on my results, which obviously would conduct to reduced the effect of School_type because it was attached to the schools.

In other word, I want to understand the effect of characteristics of schools on their results, but if I "suppress" the effect of the individuals, here the schools, in the random effects, I obviously will not get any results.

However, I have the feeling that my first formula:

```r
Result ~ School_type * Subject + (1|Year)
```

which gives me the expected results, does not take into account the fact that the data are repeated for the schools.

To explain entirely my situation, the problem I have is that my total population, the schools, I can observe is limited (to almost 50, and I have the informations on all of them) so to understand better the influence of `school_type`, I decided to collect information on five years, so that my results would be more stable.
Indeed, I'm not interested in the evolution through the year, and there is no reason of an influence over time.

What I am struggling to understand is that, if I put the `school_ID` in the random effect, would that not 'suppress' the effect of these individuals? And by doing so, is it not normal that the effect of `school_type` is reduced because embeded in the `school_ID`. What is important to me is to determine is `school_type` has an influence on the results, and I'd like to use the repetition over the year as a confirmation over the year of this influence.

[Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) helped me to understand the problem in another post I wrongfully post on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709452/which-formula-to-choose-for-a-mixed-model).

As he noted, I should not look at significance tests until you have decided that you are happy with the structure of your model, it would be scientifically problematic, and I'm fully aware of it.
However, the reason I'm doing so, is that I tested an Anova for my data for each year trying to understand if there is an effect of `school_type` on the result each year. And I found that for each year (only for 2017, *0.1 < p < 0.05*), there is a significative influence of school_type. And I'd like through this mixed effect module to 'compile' all these years.
So, yes I'm looking at the significance of the model, because I expect it to find a significative correlation, because I found it for each year separately. Hence, if it does not find one, that can only mean that it does not calculate what I expect it to do (I assume).
Here the results of the Anovas.

```r
> #### Anova on the effect of `school_type` for each year ####
> 
> dt_t_2019 <- subset(dt_test, dt_test$year == "2019")
> dt_t_2018 <- subset(dt_test, dt_test$year == "2018")
> dt_t_2017 <- subset(dt_test, dt_test$year == "2017")
> dt_t_2016 <- subset(dt_test, dt_test$year == "2016")
> dt_t_2015 <- subset(dt_test, dt_test$year == "2015")
> 
> aov_2019 <- anova_test(dt_t_2019, result ~ school_type * subject)
Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
> aov_2019
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

               Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1         school_type   2 132  9.276 1.70e-04     * 0.123
2             subject   3 132 39.281 3.29e-18     * 0.472
3 school_type:subject   6 132  0.681 6.65e-01       0.030
> aov_2018 <- anova_test(dt_t_2018, result ~ school_type * subject)
Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
> aov_2018
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

               Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1         school_type   2 119  3.603 3.00e-02     * 0.057
2             subject   3 119 36.335 9.62e-17     * 0.478
3 school_type:subject   6 119  0.327 9.22e-01       0.016
> aov_2017 <- anova_test(dt_t_2017, result ~ school_type * subject)
Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
> aov_2017
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

               Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1         school_type   2 126  2.688 7.20e-02       0.041
2             subject   3 126 31.768 2.32e-15     * 0.431
3 school_type:subject   6 126  0.742 6.16e-01       0.034
> aov_2016 <- anova_test(dt_t_2016, result ~ school_type * subject)
Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
> aov_2016
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

               Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1         school_type   2 120  5.367 6.00e-03     * 0.082
2             subject   3 120 37.329 4.10e-17     * 0.483
3 school_type:subject   6 120  0.235 9.64e-01       0.012
> aov_2015 <- anova_test(dt_t_2015, result ~ school_type * subject)
Coefficient covariances computed by hccm()
> aov_2015
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

               Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1         school_type   2 107  7.036 1.00e-03     * 0.116
2             subject   3 107 43.949 1.37e-18     * 0.552
3 school_type:subject   6 107  0.497 8.10e-01       0.027
```

When I use the following model (which take into account that I have multiple measurements per school).

```r
result ~ school_type * subject + (year|school_ID)
```

As Ben noted, it finds a small significance(for the `school_type` variable which is the variable I'm interested in). However, I do not understand why this significance is lower, although it has more data, than when I take separately each year, although in that case the data is five times lower.

This issue stay the same when I use the following models proposed by Ben:

```r
result ~ school_type * subject + (1|year) + (1|school_ID) + (1|year:school_ID)
```

and

```r
result ~ school_type * subject + year + (1|school_ID/year)
```

Again, I'm not interested in the effect of years (which there is no reason to have). The fact that I have repeated mesure has for only purpose to give more stability to my data by confirming an observation over the year.
To say it otherwise, the hierarchy of the schools considering these results is the same over the year regardless of the students. The results being the mean of the results of the students of a school. It is not the same students which pass the year each year, but others. These results are the results of students to a state exam they take at the end of high school.

This may be important. If the measure are repeated over the year on the school, they're not strictly speaking the result of the schools but of the students in the school. Considering that, they're not the result of the same students, but students coming from the same school.
I could not get the results of the students but only those of the schools for privacy reasons, and I know there is not the same number of students tested each year and between each schools, but I cannot get these numbers neither.

What I fear is that by considering the `school_ID` in the random effects, is that is 'suppress' the effect of the 'individual', but this effect is precisely the one I want to study, considering whether they are a type A school, B or C.

I hope, I've been clear.

Here is the `dput(my_data_frame)`.

```r
structure(list(result = c(69.9, 72.4, 67.1, 84.4, 84.9, 68, 78.1, 
65.1, 69.9, 77.5, 80.2, 84.7, 89.3, 82.6, 63.8, 40.8, 72.2, 71.4, 
77.2, 79.9, 93.5, 65, 67.7, 91.8, 79.6, 73.4, 80.9, 85.7, 91.8, 
67.1, 66.5, 84.6, 80.8, 87.3, 94, 87.8, 86.2, 36.6, 37.6, 18, 
30, 34.8, 32.5, 21.9, 29, 22.7, 47.3, 70, 84.6, 60.8, 42.1, 18.6, 
49.2, 33.9, 34.9, 47.1, 29.2, 34.5, 70.3, 56, 67.8, 60.9, 50.3, 
40.4, 20.8, 45.4, 57.7, 65, 26.5, 40.1, 36.6, 49.1, 52.4, 22.8, 
46.5, 42.4, 54.1, 51.3, 27.2, 42.9, 47.1, 61.6, 45.1, 86.5, 69.2, 
58.4, 58.4, 46.8, 77, 46.9, 73.1, 50.1, 61.4, 49.2, 75, 75.4, 
53.2, 71.9, 49.5, 27.4, 48.3, 51.9, 68.8, 69, 44.6, 39, 48.3, 
77.5, 59.3, 70.9, 80.1, 73.5, 77.9, 57.3, 76.8, 67, 63.2, 89.8, 
79.5, 70.8, 78.5, 79.4, 79.4, 80.5, 72, 68.6, 91.7, 75.6, 77.2, 
77.8, 73, 85.3, 68.8, 64.6, 88.2, 76.9, 84.7, 88.5, 76.6, 81.8, 
26.6, 30.9, 27.9, 33.5, 27.8, 8.7, 27.8, 31.8, 68, 23.5, 80.2, 
54.8, 42.7, 46.1, 49.6, 27, 35.2, 30, 32, 62.9, 56.6, 70.2, 44.3, 
39.3, 37, 24, 52.2, 44.2, 59.3, 30.4, 33.9, 33.8, 65.7, 42.8, 
36.5, 43.1, 49.7, 34.3, 10.4, 47.4, 43.4, 60.8, 58.5, 93.2, 81.7, 
79.4, 76.8, 66.3, 76.2, 68.2, 45, 46.7, 57.4, 89.6, 81.6, 73.8, 
61.1, 43.2, 41.9, 74.8, 56.9, 71.5, 30.9, 59.6, 39.8, 76.3, 67.3, 
54.5, 78, 92.6, 80.9, 81.7, 64, 75.2, 62.3, 75.9, 87.1, 73.1, 
64.8, 79.3, 85.4, 81.3, 74.4, 90.6, 68.7, 71.3, 92.4, 79.5, 72.1, 
86, 85.7, 90.8, 66.6, 62.8, 84.4, 77.9, 85.6, 86, 80.6, 49.4, 
42.1, 28, 35.2, 32.5, 45.6, 35.6, 38.1, 38.8, 48.3, 32.2, 84.6, 
61.4, 46.7, 68.7, 65, 26.7, 49.2, 55.2, 26.8, 21.8, 55.4, 43.4, 
56, 44, 65.2, 42.4, 41.9, 27.6, 44, 51.1, 63, 32.9, 52.3, 44.8, 
58.1, 44, 15.2, 44.2, 68.8, 53.3, 25, 57.8, 51.7, 60.8, 59.4, 
88.2, 83.6, 74.2, 81.7, 64.8, 63.4, 61.1, 46.8, 47.2, 69.4, 76.3, 
87.9, 78.7, 70.7, 60.8, 34.6, 42.3, 54.7, 62.1, 33.6, 51, 31.1, 
72.5, 66.9, 69.4, 79.5, 80.6, 80.8, 70.5, 72.5, 63.6, 96.6, 78.4, 
90.8, 75.9, 57.1, 76.2, 74.8, 59.9, 61.7, 82.6, 65.9, 73.8, 90.1, 
83.2, 78, 83.5, 83.8, 87, 67.2, 60.7, 79.9, 76.1, 82, 82.2, 84.6, 
48.1, 33, 13.5, 35.7, 42.6, 23.6, 35.4, 40.4, 41.6, 46.5, 24.6, 
78.8, 73.6, 41.1, 68.5, 45.1, 38.6, 45, 78.4, 23.9, 35.6, 55.6, 
53.3, 57.1, 63.2, 67.9, 55.2, 23.5, 41.3, 56, 50.6, 50.6, 44.2, 
44.9, 46.4, 54.6, 41.5, 30, 53.6, 81, 37.2, 48, 56.8, 77.4, 59.2, 
91.8, 77.3, 78.1, 80.8, 63.4, 54.6, 51.3, 63.5, 53.2, 76.3, 72.7, 
79.6, 57.8, 40.2, 66, 58.3, 80.4, 72.8, 53.6, 54.2, 54, 65.3, 
68.4, 79, 75.6, 81.8, 54.4, 68.5, 68.5, 77.9, 84.8, 87.1, 74.9, 
64.9, 74.1, 63.8, 76, 86, 67.9, 81.8, 91.2, 81.2, 72.2, 74.9, 
85.4, 90.8, 71, 64.5, 84.3, 83.3, 84.3, 85.1, 38.5, 46, 44.1, 
49.3, 37.9, 26.9, 36.9, 32.3, 45.2, 51.9, 84.8, 65.9, 53.3, 43.3, 
42.1, 71.4, 42.6, 29.4, 38.6, 49.5, 40.5, 63.8, 46.3, 28.7, 31.7, 
57.1, 66.1, 21.8, 37.6, 49.5, 49.9, 55.7, 53.2, 53.2, 53.2, 40.2, 
57.3, 64.4, 88.3, 74.2, 68.6, 53.4, 70.5, 52.4, 60.6, 49.6, 57.2, 
62.6, 65.5, 66.7, 52.7, 46.7, 51.1, 53.4, 56.3, 73.7, 34.7, 65.1, 
50, 54.8, 48.2, 59.8, 79, 50.1, 53, 54.8, 53.7, 52.8, 72.8, 55.4, 
90, 64.1, 50.3, 2.5, 49.3, 46, 57.9, 42.2, 93.2, 53.1, 51.5, 
80.7, 49.7, 70.9, 63.6, 63.2, 61.8, 59.3, 47.4, 54.9, 77.4, 69.7, 
66.1, 48.8, 72.1, 59.5, 58.7, 54.3, 64.4, 83.9, 52.1, 53.1, 55.1, 
63.3, 61.4, 79.5, 57.5, 68.3, 47.7, 70.4, 61, 53, 55.1, 89.2, 
60.3, 50.2, 83.1, 76.9, 69.7, 64.7, 58.8, 62, 48.5, 46, 66.1, 
74.1, 56, 69, 64.3, 54, 33.9, 58, 78.9, 53.4, 59.7, 59.1, 63.4, 
52.2, 68.5, 56, 96.5, 53.3, 47.9, 60, 66.9, 56.6, 39.7, 93.5, 
47.4, 40.1, 78.1, 63.1, 62.6, 64.3, 57.5, 56.8, 51.9, 48.8, 44.7, 
56.4, 65.2, 70, 56.2, 63.2, 53.4, 44.6, 42, 56.2, 50.3, 50.2, 
53.3, 47.5, 46.7, 64.1, 49.5, 71.9, 57.8, 37.2, 47.9, 46.9, 42.3, 
38.4, 42.9, 46.4, 73.6, 60.6, 53.2, 61, 55.4, 41.7, 47.9, 49.6, 
58.5, 63, 42.3, 65.7, 48.4, 53.5, 53.2, 51.5, 53.9, 47.8, 52.3, 
58.5, 59.9, 59.9, 74, 57.8, 44.1, 61.5, 47, 59.4, 48.9, 40.5, 
74.6, 56.6, 52.9, 72.2, 59.8, 50.1, 46.5, 68.7, 64.1, 64.6, 53.1, 
64.8), school_ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 36L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), subject = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Math", "History", "Philosiphy", 
"English"), class = "factor"), school_type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-664L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

*I wrongfully asked this question on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709452/which-formula-to-choose-for-a-mixed-model)*